# Conditional Expectation of a random variable with itself

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability

Suppose $Y$ is either positive or integrable on $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$.

Then, how do I show that $E(Y|Y)=Y$ a.s.?

Seems so basic, but I know there's got to be a trick to it.

Comment: I assume that $Y$ generates $\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: The problem doesn't say anything about that. Y appears to be $\mathcal{A}$ measurable, however, so wouldn't it then also be $\mathcal{G}$ measurable?

Comment: If $\left( {\Omega ,\mathcal{A},P} \right) = \left( {\left[ {0,1} \right],\mathcal{B}\left( {\left[ {0,1} \right]} \right),{{\left. \lambda  \right|}_{\left[ {0,1} \right]}}} \right)$ and  $Y:\left[ {0,1} \right] \to \mathbb{R},Y\left( \omega  \right) = \omega $, then $Y$ is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable, but not $\left\{ {\emptyset ,\left[ {0,1} \right]} \right\}$-measurable.

Comment: So what you're saying is that, basically if $\mathcal{G}$ is the trivial sigma algebra, what I said would not be true?

Comment: Yes. Also, possibly for many, many more sigma algebras.

Comment: What is your source for this exercise?

Comment: Probability Essentials by Jacod & Protter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $Y$ generates $\mathcal{G}$. Then

$\mathbb{E}\left[ {{1_G}\mathbb{E}\left[ {Y|Y} \right]} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ {{1_G}\mathbb{E}\left[ {Y|\mathcal{G}} \right]} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ {{1_G}Y} \right],\forall G \in \mathcal{G}$

since a product of $\mathcal{G}$-measurable functions is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and by using properties of conditional expectation, from the definition of conditional expectation it follows that $Y = \mathbb{E}\left[ {Y|Y} \right]$ $P$-a.s.

Comment: And what if it doesn't generate $\mathcal{G}$? As I said, the problem does not say that it does, and I don't want to make extra assumptions. Unless I'm missing something here that you might want to clue me on on?

Comment: $\mathcal{G}$ in your question is unnecessary. In full generality, $Y$ generates some $\sigma $-algebra, which I denoted $\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. I'm having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around conditional expectation.

Comment: Let me help you with an example, which I'll post as another answer.

Comment: Somebody should probably mention that the hypothesis that G=sigma(Y) is not needed, hence a solution should not be based on this (restrictive) assumption.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{E}\left[ {X|Y} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ {X|\mathcal{G}} \right]$ by definition, where $\mathcal{G} = \sigma \left( Y \right)$ ($\mathcal{G}$ in my answer is not related to the one in the question), the condition is unavoidable rather than restrictive

Comment: Here is a piece of advice: when in need of denoting a new object, do not use a notation already used in the question.

Comment: Notation $\mathcal{G}$ for a sigma-algebra is pretty common and it is as relevant to the rest of the question as the appendix is to a human. I've suggested the part to be removed

Answer (score 3):

Let $\left( {\Omega ,\mathcal{A},P} \right) = \left( {\left[ 0 \right.,\left. 1 \right\rangle ,\mathcal{B}\left[ 0 \right.,\left. 1 \right\rangle ,{{\left. \lambda  \right|}_{\left[ 0 \right.,\left. 1 \right\rangle }}} \right)$ and $Y:\left[ 0 \right.,\left. 1 \right\rangle  \to \mathbb{R},Y\left( \omega  \right) = \omega $.

Consider a sequence of $\sigma $-algebras ${\mathcal{G}_n} = \sigma \left\{ {\left[ {\frac{i}{n}} \right.,\left. {\frac{{i + 1}}{n}} \right\rangle :i \in \left\{ {0,1, \ldots ,n - 1} \right\}} \right\}$ (it can be shown that a sigma-algebra generated by a finite partition is equal to all possible unions of that partition).

Consider $\mathbb{E}\left[ {Y|{\mathcal{G}_2}} \right]$. ${\mathcal{G}_2} = \left\{ {\emptyset ,\left[ 0 \right.,\left. {\frac{1}{2}} \right\rangle ,\left[ {\frac{1}{2}} \right.,\left. 1 \right\rangle ,\left[ 0 \right.,\left. 1 \right\rangle } \right\}$ and for each $G \in {\mathcal{G}_2}$, the following property must hold:

$\mathbb{E}\left[ {{1_G}\mathbb{E}\left[ {Y|{\mathcal{G}_2}} \right]} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ {{1_G}Y} \right]$. So,

$\mathbb{E}\left[ {{1_{\left[ 0 \right.,\left. {\frac{1}{2}} \right\rangle }}\mathbb{E}\left[ {Y|{\mathcal{G}_2}} \right]} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ {{1_{\left[ 0 \right.,\left. {\frac{1}{2}} \right\rangle }}Y} \right] = \frac{1}{4}$

$\mathbb{E}\left[ {{1_{\left[ {\frac{1}{2}} \right.,\left. 1 \right\rangle }}\mathbb{E}\left[ {Y|{\mathcal{G}_2}} \right]} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ {{1_{\left[ {\frac{1}{2}} \right.,\left. 1 \right\rangle }}Y} \right] = \frac{3}{4}$

Since ${\mathbb{E}\left[ {Y|{\mathcal{G}_2}} \right]}$ is ${{\mathcal{G}_2}}$-measurable, it must be constant on ${\left[ 0 \right.,\left. {\frac{1}{2}} \right\rangle ,\left[ {\frac{1}{2}} \right.,\left. 1 \right\rangle }$ (show it as an exercise), so

$\mathbb{E}\left[ {Y|{\mathcal{G}_2}} \right]\left( \omega  \right) = \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \frac{1}{4} & ,\omega  \in \left[ 0 \right.,\left. {\frac{1}{2}} \right\rangle  \\
  \frac{3}{4} & ,\omega  \in \left[ {\frac{1}{2}} \right.,\left. 1 \right\rangle   \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.$

Analogously, it can be seen that $\mathbb{E}\left[ {Y|{\mathcal{G}_n}} \right]\left( \omega  \right) = \frac{{\frac{i}{n} + \frac{{i + 1}}{n}}}{2},\omega  \in \left[ {\frac{i}{n}} \right.,\left. {\frac{{i + 1}}{n}} \right\rangle $.

So, as we make ${{\mathcal{G}_n}}$ finer and finer, ${\mathbb{E}\left[ {Y|{\mathcal{G}_n}} \right]}$ resembles $Y$ more and more, and is equal to restricted expecation of $Y$ on all sets where it must be constant, namely on the basic "building blocks" of ${{\mathcal{G}_n}}$.

I suggest you draw first 4 or 5 conditional expectations with respect to given sigma algebras, the image is most illustrative.

Comment: Let me see if I got the hang of it by throwing out another example: if $Y=\alpha$ a.s., with $\alpha$ a constant, and I wanted to show that $E\{Y|\mathcal{G}\}=\alpha$ a.s,. Then I would write $E\{1_{G}E\{Y|\mathcal{G}\}\}=E\{1_{G}E\{\alpha|\mathcal{G}\}\}=E\{1_{G}\alpha\}$, and then by properties of conditional expectation, we have that $E\{Y|\mathcal{G}\}=\alpha$?

Comment: Exactly as stated, except the last claim follows from the definition of conditional expectation, not a property.

Comment: Definition: $Y = \mathbb{E}\left[ {X|\mathcal{G}} \right]$ is a conditional expectation of $X$ with respect to $\mathcal{G}$ if $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and $\mathbb{E}\left[ {{1_G}Y} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ {{1_G}X} \right]$ for all $G \in \mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, Alen; you're the greatest! :)